# Getting user's email address from text field

Tags: email, formula

I have names of users populated in a text field ("[First Name] "[Last Name]"). What I would like to do is get the email addresses associated with these names if they're registered in the system.

Is there a way to query the email address of a user given their name, username, or ID? I'm able to display the currently logged in user's email address using $User.Email, but I'm not sure how to apply this to get another user's email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better if you created a lookup to the Contact / User record and instead associated the records?  Then the email could be exposed via a formula field..    You could even populate this lookup via a trigger based upon the user first / last name.  :)

Comment: Yup - it would be and this is what I ended up doing. I now have a lookup going to a contact object and pulling the email field that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a trigger on this record (before update), that takes the names of these users, and then uses SOQL to query the user object.

select Id, Email from User where Name in :[List of Names from the text field]

Format the result accordingly, and save it in the text field you want to save the emails in.

But yes, like Benjamin said, if you only have 1 user's name in this field, just use a lookup field and then you can get their emails in a formula field.

If you have more than 1 name(s) in this text field like [Jon Doe, Frank B, Scott Fitzgerald] etc., then you may use the trigger approach. I am not sure what kind of a field this is.